# How to get the last two mini games

Tags: super-mario-party

I have two "free-for-all" mini games to unlock, in the minigame place where it shows all the mingames they both are between "timing is money" and "air to a fortune" I played through a whole board but did not get them, is there a certain board or mode I need to play to unlock them?

I looked it up and I Am 
https://www.mariowiki.com/Follow_the_Money
https://www.mariowiki.com/Lightning_Round

I can only find info on how to easily unlock Allie or two vs two minigames when I look it up on how to unlock

Comment: My guess is you just need to keep playing. From my experience the game will continue to unlock games you have not played until they are all unlocked. If you have only played one board, try playing through the other ones. Im sure you will have unlocked them all by then.